# Convert D depth BST to D number of Linked List

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is a interview question
Given a BST, design an algorithm which  creates a linked list of all the nodes at each depth. i.e. if you have a tree of depth D then you will have D linked list.

I thought of starting with the level order traversal but i stucked. Please help.

Comment: It sounds like kind of homework

Comment: Besides, if you got stuck, you probably have code to show us. Also, a tree of depth D has 2^N-1 nodes, not D.

Comment: Sir.. I thought of doing the level order traversal. What we need is to keep track of levels. For that i am inserting a NULL in the queue.I created an array of head pointers (for list) and since i know all the nodes in a particular level (stored in the queue), i can simply create the list for every level. But i think something better can be done. Please help.!